# Как отправить файл POST запросом из php-скрипта?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Приветствую. Цель - менять фотографию чата ВК, для этого, как написано в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files_2?f=5.+%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0), нужно сделать следующее:

> Передайте файл на адрес upload_url, полученный в предыдущем пункте, сформировав POST-запрос с полем file. Это поле должно содержать изображение в формате multipart/form-data.

Вот мой код:

```
$ch = curl_init($upload_url);
$curlfile = curl_file_create(__DIR__.'\1.jpg', 'multipart/form-data', 'file');
$data = array("file"=>$curlfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Но если сделать дамп `curl_getinfo()`, то там content-type установлен на `application/json;`. И ВК отдаёт ошибку `Bad format file`. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multipart/form-data` заголовок и соответствующее валидное тело запроса сформирует curl самостоятельно как только в CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS получит массив, а не строку.

В `curl_file_create` необходимо указывать `mime` тип самого файла. Например, `image/jpeg` для jpg-изображения. Можно никакое не указывать и файл будет отправлен с примечанием `application/octet-stream`.

А в `curl_getinfo` вы видите заголовок `Content-Type` ответа на ваш запрос. vk отвечает в JSON, вот и тип ответа они отдают верно. Свои заголовки запроса можно посмотреть в `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` если перед выполнением запроса в `curl_setopt` включить настройку `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT`

```
$ch = curl_init($upload_url);
$curlfile = curl_file_create(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'1.jpg');
$data = array("file"=>$curlfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Чтобы не гадать, под какой вы ОС, заменил вдобавок разделитель директорий на штатную константу. Если файл удовлетворяет требованиям vk, то он должен успешно загрузиться.

Comment: Теперь получаю ошибку `Upload error: photo was not resized`. Что это значит?

Comment: Проверьте своё изображение, отвечает ли оно требованиям api. Можете отправить изображение куда-нибудь на свой скрипт и проверить, что оно приходит в $_FILES.

Comment: Проверил, в массив `$_FILES` картинка попадает, хотя не получается сделать `move_uploaded_file`. Проверил требования, вроде бы все нормально - картинка jpeg 1000x500, весит ~70 кб. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В  представленном коде больше ничего в глаза не бросается. Возможно ошибка на предыдущем шаге. Или вообще у самого сервиса.

Comment: А по каким причинам может не работать `move_uploaded_file`? Во временной папке картинка не появляется.

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар на подзарядке.

Comment: Мистика какая-то. Всё заработало. Спасибо за помощь.